# Check if substring is in a list of strings and return the containing string

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, dictionary

Consider the following code:

```
resultsClient = [] 
dict = {} 

    if any(str(client) in str(s) for s in arrayMessages):
        resultsClient.append(client)
        // add key pair <client , containingMessage>
        dict[client] = ... // <<<<========================= put something here
    else:
        missed = missed + 1
```

How can I get the containing string that fits to the if condition  `if any(str(client) in str(s) for s in arrayMessages)` , and put in in the dictionary `dict` ?

Comment: You should edit this to be a [mcve] with example input and expected output.

Comment: I don't know if you want all the matches or just the first one but this might be a starting point: Compute ALL the strings matching your criteria `dict[client] = [i for s in arrayMessages if str(client) in i]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

```
>>> data = ['Python', 'Hello', 'World']
>>> next(value for value in data if 'Hell' in value)
'Hello'
```

You will get an error if you don't find an element.

```
>>> next(value for value in data if 'Hall' in value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    next(value for value in data if 'Hall' in value)
StopIteration
```

That's what the `default` parameter of `next` is for.

```
>>> next((value for value in data if 'Hall' in value), None)
```

This will give you `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the title, ***Check if substring is in a list of strings and return the containing string***:

```
def stuff(substring, listofstrings):
  for item in listofstrings:
    if substring in item:
      return item
```

Even if one doesn't immediately remember `next()`, Python itself does not mandate forgetting to write code completely.